# Vue.js: unwanted effect every time the view is rendered

Tags: vue.js, view, vue-component, vue-router, rerender

the problem is when browsing between Views, cause this effect. render first the state active(gray) and then, the state Done (red). I don't know if I'm building this in the wrong way or its normal behavior

[image]

I have the following in this view:

Template

```
 <div class="col"  v-for="item in category" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <router-link :id="item.id" class="btn-category" :class="item.status"
       v-bind:to="{ name: 'words', params : { id: item.id} }" >
         <span>{{item.content}}
           <div class="icon-circle" > 
              <icon v-if="item.status == 'cat-done'" name="check" class="icon icon-s"></icon>
              <icon v-else name="arrow-go" class="icon icon-s"></icon>
           </div> 
         </span>
    </router-link>
 </div>
```

then

```
data(){
    return {
      id:'',
      category:[],
      countCatDone:0,
    }
 },
 created(){
        this.getCatLevel()
    },
```

```
 getCatLevel(){
    this.id = this.$route.params.id
        db.collection("da-content").where("contenido_id", "==", this.$route.params.id )
        .get()
        .then( query=> {    
            let items = [] 
            query.forEach( doc => {
                let object = doc.data();
                object.id = doc.id;
                object.status = "null";
                db.collection("da-content-log").where("contenido_id", "==", doc.id)
                .where("usuario_id", "==", this.user.email )
                .get()
                .then(respond => {
                    if(respond.empty){
                        object.status = "cat-active";
                    } else {
                        respond.forEach((doc) => {
                            object.status = doc.data().status;
                            if (object.status == "cat-done") {
                                this.countCatDone++
                            }
                        })
                    }    
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
                });
                items.push(object);
            });
            this.category = items;                        
            
        })
},
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is normal behavior because the data of checked category is taken from `this.getCatLevel()` which is an `async` function, so your items will be rendered earlier before the data is fully loaded. My suggestion is to add some `loading` information in the UI, or you hide it when the data is not fully loaded like by adding a data variable `isLoading` then call it inside `getCatLevel()`, for the example:

```
getCatLevel(){
this.isLoading = true; //set the loading value to true before calling data
....
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
}).finally(()=> {this.isLoading = false}); // set loading value to false when data is fully loaded
....
```

then call it in the element

```
<div v-if="!isLoading" class="col"  v-for="item in category" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <router-link :id="item.id" class="btn-category" :class="item.status"
       v-bind:to="{ name: 'words', params : { id: item.id} }" >
         <span>{{item.content}}
           <div class="icon-circle" > 
              <icon v-if="item.status == 'cat-done'" name="check" class="icon icon-s"></icon>
              <icon v-else name="arrow-go" class="icon icon-s"></icon>
           </div> 
         </span>
    </router-link>
 </div>
```